# Check if Ethereum domain name is registered python

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, python-requests, ethereum

I am trying to see if an ether domain name is registered.

For example `"yaz.eth"` is a domain name that I own and have registered. If we look at a domain name such as `"radomname.eth"` we can see that it is not registered.

Ideally, I want to be able to check if a lot of names are registered, 1000+. You can use a website such as [ether scan](https://etherscan.io) to [see if a domain is registered.](https://etherscan.io/enslookup-search?search=radomname.eth) The issue here is that there is a limit of 14 requests per minute.

Ive tried using python requests to scrape results but I get a max of `14 per minute` which is far from what I need.

I also tried using `proxies` but I don't have enough to scrape at the rate I need to. Cloudflare also blocks some proxies making them useless.

Comment: "Is there an API?" is asking for an off-site resource, which is off-topic. Refer [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [Ethereum node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513) yourself without API limitations. Then you can use Python and [web3.py ENS API](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ens_overview.html) to check the registration status of ENS domains.